# Itô formula + SDE

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

I have a problem with solving the following problem:

[image]

I.e. I want to show that $X_t$ is a solution to the SDE by employing the Itō formula. Now the problem is I don't get how I should set the function to show this with the Itō formula/lemma. I've tried setting $Z_t:=\ \int_0^{t}... ds$ and then $X_t:=f(t,X_t), f(t,z)=x_0e^{\sigma B_t-\sigma^2t/2}+\alpha z$ but I ended up with another expression for $dX_t$. Could anyone help me how to show that $X_t$ is the solution to the SDE with the help of the Itô formula?

Comment: Which version of Itô's formula do you know?

Comment: I know that if $X_t$ is an ito process and $Z_t=f(t,X_t)$ then:

$dZ_t=f_t(t,X_t)dt+f_x(t,X_t)dX_t+1/2f_{xx}(t,X_t)d<X>_t$. Also on integral form!

Comment: Do you know how to apply it for a multidimensional Itô process, e.g. for $X_t= (Y_t,Z_t)$ where both $(Y_t)_{t \geq 0}$ and $(Z_t)_{t \geq 0}$ are (one-dimensional) Itô processes?

Comment: Hmm, I think that's what I am missing in my solution. I don't know how to apply it for a multidimensional ito process but if I were to guess then: $d(ZtYt)=ZtdYt+YtdZt+d<Z,Y>t.$ Do you imply that I should rewrite $X_t$ into a product between $Bt, Bs$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $(Y_t)_{t \geq 0}$ and $(Z_t)_{t \geq 0}$ are one-dimensional Itô processes and $f \in C_b^2$. Then Itô's formula states

$$\begin{align*} f(t,Y_t,Z_t)-f(0,Y_0,Z_0) &= \int_0^t f_y(s,Y_s,Z_s) \, dY_s + \int_0^t f_z(s,Y_s,Z_s) \, dZ_s + \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t f_{yy}(s,Y_s,Z_s) \, d\langle Y \rangle_s \\ &\quad + \int_0^t f_{xz}(s,Y_s,Z_s) \, d\langle Y,Z \rangle_s + \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t f_{zz}(s,Y_s,Z_s) \, d\langle Z \rangle_s \\ &\quad + \int_0^t f_t(s,Y_s,Z_s) \, ds. \end{align*}$$

Apply this to

$$Y_t := B_t \qquad \quad Z_t := \int_0^t e^{-\sigma B_s + \frac{\sigma^2}{2}s} \, ds \qquad f(t,y,z) := e^{\sigma y - \sigma^2/2 t} (x_0+\alpha z).$$ (Note that $X_t = f(t,Y_t,Z_t)$.)

Comment: Thanks, that's how I defined my function after your comments. It seems however to be some difference in notations when it comes to the ito formula, is it the standard to express it on integral form or on the differentiable form (or perhaps it does not matter since they are equivalent). Anyway, thanks. I realized that the crucial part is to learn how to define the functions!